# ASP. Net Project Port Number Change

Tags: asp.net, port-number

I unloaded my ASP. Project Then reloaded it.

When I Run my project it requires that I should set my project as "Set as Start Up Project" - I made the requested action

The problem is, when I perform "Set as Start Up Project" it changes the default port number of my project. The previous port number is ":5432".

I tried to assign the port number to the project and change the generated port number from "Set as Start Up Project" action.

But It shows an error : "Port 5432 is in Use".

I need to run it again on port "5432"

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: close all visual studio instances and reload.

Comment: still the assigns it to different port number

Comment: May be this could help. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667443/Change-default-Port-for-the-ASP-NET-Development-Se

Comment: @AnoopH.N I already did this but it says "Port 5432 is in use"

Comment: Yes but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You probably have postgresql database running in your machine. Postgres default port is 5432. In the "run" of windows type services.msc press enter. In that services-manager window locate the postgres service and stop it. Then try to run your program on 5432.